In a mixed effects model, can leaving out the intercept-slope correlation parameter inflate type I error?
I am considering leaving out the intercept-slope correlation parameter in a mixed effects model to avoid convergence issues (i.e., in nlme::lme, random = list(~1|individual, ~0+time|individual)).
Is it "safe" to do this in the sense that it won't result in inflated type I error probability of the associated fixed slope?
I have already run some simulations for myself to see that leaving out the random slope altogether (random = ~1|individual) can definitely increase the chance of false discoveries, but I'm not confident about using simulations to check about the correlation because the full model (random=~time|individual) fails to converge so often for my simulated data.
This question helped a lot in understanding the implications of omitting the correlation parameter, but it doesn't address type I error.
